# Equivalent of mass*force constant in LC oscillations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-current, harmonic-oscillator, inductance

Comparing the L-C oscillations with the oscillations of a spring-block system (force constant of spring = k and mass of block = m), to what electrical expression is the physical expression mk equal to?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1 (analysis):**

In a spring block system, we have the following quantities:

$m =$ source of inertia, resistance to change of velocity

$k =$ spring constant, spring stores the kinetic energy as potential energy

$x =$ displacement

$v =$ velocity, the rate of change of displacement

$$$$

In an LC oscillator, we have the following quantities:

$L =$ inductance, resistance to change in current

$C =$ capacitance, stores the electrical energy as potential energy

$q =$ charge

$i =$ current, the rate of flow of charge

$$$$

If you try to draw an analogy, you can obviously see that the mass is analogous to inductance. It isn't hard to draw an analogy between displacement and charge either. Even the analogy between velocity and current is obvious.

The tricky part is the relation between the spring constant and capacitance.

A higher spring constant indicates that the spring is more stiff (does not allow too much displacement for given energy). A higher capacitance indicates that it isn't that stiff and can store more charge for a given potential difference.

Therefore, $k$ is analogous to $\frac{1}{C}$.

$$$$

---

$$$$
**Method 2 (equations):**

In a spring block system, we have the following equations:

$Kinetic \space Energy = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$

$Potential \space Energy = \frac{1}{2}kx^2$

$$$$

In an LC oscillator, we have the following equations:

$Magnetic \space Energy = \frac{1}{2}Li^2$

$Electrical \space Energy = \frac{1}{2}\frac{q^2}{C} $

You can clearly identify the pairs of equivalent/similar quantities by comparing variables in the two sets of equations.